# how to catch exception thrown by imageWithData: iPhone

Tags: iphone, exception, uiimage

I want to try to create an image using NSdata. If imageWithData: method of UIImage can create it successfully, i will follow a path but if it cannot create i want to follow another way.

Is this even possible?

I tried

```
    @try {
        im = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        NSLog(@"Trying");
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception");    
        anotherData = doSomethingWithData(data)
        im = [UIImage imageWithData:anotherData];
    }
    @finally {
        NSLog(@"Final");
        [self.questionList addObject:im];
    }
```

but it causes app to crash.

How can I catch this exception without causing app to crash?

Exception is this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0'
```

Code does not create image from data but still it does not throws an exception or anything about it. Is there a way that I can understand if image is created or not.

Comment: What is the error that is being thrown?

Comment: I recon `NSInvalidArgumentException` can not be caught.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error, because `im` remains `nil` and you are not allowed to add `nil` to an array.

You could do it like that:

```
im = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

if(im == nil) {
    anotherData = doSomethingWithData(data)
    im = [UIImage imageWithData:anotherData];
}

if(im != nil)
    [self.questionList addObject:im];
```

Answer (score 0):

An implementation similar to your pattern above would be to re-write the finally block like such:

```
@finally {
   NSLog(@"Final");
   if(im) {
       [self.questionList addObject:im];
   }
}
```

However the entire piece of code could easily be re-written (and should) to not require exception handling.

Comment: @harakiri's code snippet is a perfect example re-writing without the use of exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After Kevin's question I realized that the image which I am trying to build is nil and I used just 'if' blocks.